Puzzles where the goal is to avoid being checkmated in x or fewer moves
Is there a name for puzzles where the goal is to avoid being checkmated in x moves?
An example is this puzzle:
[Title "White to play and avoid being mated on or before move 4 (there is a unique solution)"]
[FEN "8/3r3K/8/7k/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kg8 Kg5 2. Kf8 Kf6 3. Kg8 Ra7 4. Kh8


I bet there are already chess problems with the stipulation "White to draw" and a retro twist (there are already 50-x moves played, so White merely has to survive x moves, as in your idea). Otherwise, this seems totally original to me.

Usually this would be (with colors revered) the refutation of a try in a direct mate problem.

Why not 3. Ke8?

3 Ke8? Rd6(d5,d4,etc.) 4 Kf8 Rd8#.
